# how to add button at the begin of box layout?

Tags: java, swing, boxlayout

I have a panel which contains a Horizontal Box within the Box there is 2 button.
Now i extende this class and want to add new button at the begin of box.
What i tried addes button to the end of box.

**any body know how to do it?**

```
 private class MyBoxPanel extends BoxPanel {
         public JButton btnPrint;
        public MyConfirmationPanel() {
            btnPrint = new JButton("print");
            add(btnPrint);
            add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(5, 0)));
        }

        protected void confirmActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for (PrinterInputListener listener : listeners)
                listener.printConfirmed(printerPanel.getPrint().getId());
        }

        protected void cancelActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for (PrinterInputListener listener : listeners)
                listener.printCancelled();
        }
    }
```

Comment: > What i tried addes button to the end of box.

- last JComponent is added to the end of (ZOrder), 1. you have to getComponentAt(int), 2. add JButton 3. moving with current JCmoponet to index +1, 4. then to call revalidate and repaint

Comment: Cant you create a panel with borderlayout withing this panel, and the set the 2 intial buttons center and east, adding the 3 one west?

Comment: In MyBoxPanel i can add any thing that i want but in BoxPanel i'm not allow to change or add anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What i tried addes button to the end of box.

Yes, the `add(component)` method just adds the component to the end of the container.

If you want to add the component to the beginning then you need to specify an index value of 0. Read the Container API for the appropriate method. I don't remember if it is `add(component, index)` or `add(index, component)`.

Then once you add the component you need to invoke

```
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```